# removing the ' ' and \n in strling list in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a string list:

```
['', '', '1.200003317775e-04\n']
```

How to remove '' and \n in this string

```
['1.200003317775e-04']
```

Thank you

Comment: \n is always present in end or it may come in first or in between in the list?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [89]: L = ['', '', '1.200003317775e-04\n']

In [90]: [i.rstrip() for i in L if i!='']
Out[90]: ['1.200003317775e-04']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following list comprehension:

```
[item.strip() for item in lst if item]
```

As such:

```
>>> lst = ['', '', '1.200003317775e-04\n']
>>> [item.strip() for item in lst if item]
['1.200003317775e-04']
>>>
```